# Internal rails notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an rails app, which imports some stuff from external service. At the end of that import, user should get an info about how many new items has been imported (it's like a periodical check, which adds just new items to local database. Not all of them each time.). A whole process and method-chain is quite complex so i'm looking for a best-practice on how to pass such information from deeply nested method. Schema looks more or less like that:

```
some_controller.rb
  -> Model.method()
    -> Lib1.method1()
      -> Lib2.method2()
        -> Lib3.method3()
          -> Lib4.method4()
            -> Lib5.method5()
              -> items_import_method()
```

and i need to somehow pass info about how many new items has been imported from `items_imported_method()` to `some_controller.rb` (or any other place this import is fired). The most obvious way of doing that is passing `new_items_count` var all the way up though this whole method chain but it seems a bit wrong to me. Isn't there any better way?

I was thinking about some kind of internal events/messages system which would let me to subscribe to some custom channel, like activeresource events but maybe there is some well-known and suggested approach for such situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not sufficient to just run it and then afterwards (in the controller) do a db query to see how many new objects have been imported in the time since before running it?

Comment: yeah, that's another solution i was thinking about but it looks a bit dirty to me ;)

Comment: I agree it's not the most elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to tackle this is to create some kind of context container object that has properties any of those steps can manipulate, then pass this in to each method on the way down.

For example:

```
class ContextExample
  attr_accessor :example_field
end
```

In practice:

```
@context = ContextExample.new

Lib1.method1(@context)

@context.example_field
# => "Test!"
```

Where what you're doing is:

```
module Lib1
  def self.method1(context)
    Lib2.method2(context)
  end
end

module Lib2
  def self.method2(context)
    context.example_field = "Test!"
  end
end
```

These modules or classes can save `context` if required, and pass it on when necessary.

If you have well-defined properties you need to set and manipulate, a class with `attr_accessor` for those usually works pretty well. If it's a more arbitrary thing and you're not sure what might shake out in the end, either use a Hash or an [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) object to capture whatever might come up.